# requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [Error 2] no such file or directory

Tags: python, python-requests, pyinstaller, instagram-api

Have some code, it works with raw code but once i turned it into a executable with pyinstaller i get the `requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [Error 2] no such file or directory`
it always works with raw code but not with pyinstaller

tried using requests from both python 2 and python3, tried on multiple PCs.

i expect it to execute the code when using a .exe with pyinstaller

Comment: Please post the code, what are we supposed to do without it?

Comment: i wouldn't know what code to share because it has multiple option and some options run fine and others give me the error and its about 800 lines of code

Comment: So create a smaller example that shows the problem and post that code. And post the full stack trace of the error. See [mre]

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution by using certifi to resolve the full path to the 'cacert.pem' cert. And use it in request:

```py
import requests
import certifi

req_url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
response = requests.get(req_url, timeout=10, verify=certifi.where()).json()
print(response)
```

If you use another cert or want to move to final binary it can be copied into pyinstaller too and use it into `verify` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Post some code, without it I am going blindly. But i can guest that  you have somewhere in your code relative(like ./file), while everything is in your original directory(raw code) it works, but after compiling,programm can't find it

Comment: i wouldn't know what code to share because it has multiple option and some options run fine and others give me the error and its about 800 lines of code

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

Using auto-py-to-exe and pyinstaller to convert to exe.

Click in "on file" button use "one directory" option.

Then you have to go to your python's directory and find the directory "requests".

Copy this directory ("requests") to your app directory created with auto-py-to-exe.

It's done.